# How to properly add governors to a CPU's scaling_available_governors on Linux

Tags: linux, cpu, linux-kernel

I want to use the userspace scaling frequency governor, but cannot figure out how to properly add the governor to my list of available governors.

I have compiled each of the potential CPUfreq scaling governors into my 4.12.9 kernel, and have even set my desired governor as the default:

```
# grep FREQ .config
CONFIG_ACPI_CPU_FREQ_PSS=y
CONFIG_CPU_FREQ=y
CONFIG_CPU_FREQ_GOV_ATTR_SET=y
CONFIG_CPU_FREQ_GOV_COMMON=y
CONFIG_CPU_FREQ_STAT=y
# CONFIG_CPU_FREQ_DEFAULT_GOV_PERFORMANCE is not set
# CONFIG_CPU_FREQ_DEFAULT_GOV_POWERSAVE is not set
CONFIG_CPU_FREQ_DEFAULT_GOV_USERSPACE=y
# CONFIG_CPU_FREQ_DEFAULT_GOV_ONDEMAND is not set
# CONFIG_CPU_FREQ_DEFAULT_GOV_CONSERVATIVE is not set
CONFIG_CPU_FREQ_GOV_PERFORMANCE=y
CONFIG_CPU_FREQ_GOV_POWERSAVE=y
CONFIG_CPU_FREQ_GOV_USERSPACE=y
CONFIG_CPU_FREQ_GOV_ONDEMAND=y
CONFIG_CPU_FREQ_GOV_CONSERVATIVE=y
CONFIG_X86_PCC_CPUFREQ=y
CONFIG_X86_ACPI_CPUFREQ=y
CONFIG_X86_ACPI_CPUFREQ_CPB=y
CONFIG_X86_AMD_FREQ_SENSITIVITY=m
CONFIG_PM_DEVFREQ=y
# DEVFREQ Governors
CONFIG_DEVFREQ_GOV_SIMPLE_ONDEMAND=y
CONFIG_DEVFREQ_GOV_PERFORMANCE=y
CONFIG_DEVFREQ_GOV_POWERSAVE=y
CONFIG_DEVFREQ_GOV_USERSPACE=y
CONFIG_DEVFREQ_GOV_PASSIVE=y
# DEVFREQ Drivers
CONFIG_PM_DEVFREQ_EVENT=y
```

However, I am only ever able to access two such governors:

```
# cat /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu0/cpufreq/scaling_available_governors 
performance powersave
```

I've done a bit of searching around and have seen that some scaling governors are not available in certain patches (according to [this](https://forums.gentoo.org/viewtopic-t-1002538-start-0.html)), such as the RT patch.  However, I do not have this patch applied to my kernel so I am unsure what I'm doing incorrectly (or what I am missing).

```
# uname -a
Linux blufor 4.12.9-MP #5 SMP Sat Oct 7 17:58:46 EDT 2017 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

Comment: @don_crissti Having initially posted and searched only on the superuser stack exchange, I did not come across your previous answer.  The questions do seem to be identical, and I will test out your solution from the other thread as soon as possible.  Out of curiosity, if your solution does not apply to me, is it better to update my post here or mention that the solution didn't work in the comment section of your solution?